# How should I optimize this code?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

```
def f(n):
    Total_Triangles = 0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        term = 3**(i-1)
        Total_Triangles+=term
    return Total_Triangles
Q = int(input())
for i in range(Q):
    n = int(input())
    Ans = f(n)*4 +1
    print(Ans%1000000007)
```

How to tackle with Time limit error in this code?

Comment: Find a faster expression for `f(n) = sum from i=1 to n of 3^(i-1) = sum from i=0 to n-1 of 3^i`.

Comment: that's what i'm asking

Comment: See the below answer for an explicit solution, but I would suggest you read how the result is derived: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula

Comment: I replaced that part with geometric series formula but still, It is showing TLE. Maybe it is the iterative part below the function which is taking more time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Karan has a good answer. It will speed up your original approach, but you still end up calculating huge numbers. Fortunately, Python's Long type can do that, but I expect that it isn't as efficient as the native 32-bit or 64-bit integer types.

You are told to give the answer modulo a huge number M, 1,000,000,007. You can improve the algorithm by using [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) throughout, so that your numbers never get very big. In modular arithmetic, this is true:

```
(a + b) % M == (a % M + b % M) % M
(a * b) % M == (a % M * b % M) % M
```

One approach could be to calculate all possible Q  values up front using modular arithmetic:

```
M = 1000000007

def makef(m):
    """Generator to create all sum(3**i) mod M"""

    n = 1
    s = 0

    for i in range(m):
        yield s

        s = (s + n) % M
        n = ((n  + n) % M + n) % M

f = list(makef(100000))
Q = int(input())

for i in range(Q):
    n = int(input())
    print (f[n] * 4 + 1) % M
```

This will do the calculations in a big loop, but only once and should be fast enough for your requirements.

Python offers you a second way: The expression `a ** b` is mapped to the in-built function `pow(a, b)`. This function can take a third parameter: a base for modular arithmetic, so that `pow(a, b, M)` will calculate `(a ** b) % M` without generating huge intermediate results.

Now you can use Karan's neat formula. But wait, there's a pitfall: You have to divide the result of the power by two. The modular relationships above are not true of division. For example, `(12 // 2) % M` is 6, but if you applied the modulo operator first, as the `pow` function does, you'd get `((12 % 2) // 2) % M`, which is 1 and not what you want. A solution is to calculate the power modulo `2 * M` and then divide by 2:

```
def f(n):
    return pow(3, n, 2 * 1000000007) // 2

Q = int(input())
for i in range(Q):
    n = int(input())
    print (f(n) * 4 + 1) % M
```

(Note that all powers of 3 are odd, so I have removed the `- 1` and let the integer division do the work.)

Side note: The value of `M` is chosen so that the addition of two numbers that are smaller than `M` fits in a signed 32-bit integer. That means that users of C, C++ or Java don't have to use bignum libraries. But note that `3 * n` can still overflow a signed int, so that you have to take care when multiplying by three: Use `((n + n) % M + n) % M` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You want to find `3 ** 0 + 3 ** 1 ... + 3 ** (n - 1)`, this is just a geometric series with first term `a = 1`, common ratio `r = 3` and number of terms `n = n`, and using the summation of a geometric series formula, we can find `f(n)` much faster when defined as so:

```
def f(n):
    return (3 ** n - 1) // 2
```

Comment: You are the true savior, I missed this high school stuff. Thanks

Comment: Sorry to disturb again but after this change Its still TLE without any fraction of second of improvement. Limit is 5sec I'm having 25 sec

Comment: Unless there is a pattern in the values of n you are given, I don't think you can improve the solution, if you are allowed to use any language, perhaps try using C (it is much faster than python for this kind of stuff)

Comment: I'll look for this.